# Malicious pop-up in Chrome: "WARNING! Please Install Update To Continue."

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Does anyone know how to get rid of this pop-up:

> The page at new1getallfilesnow.maynemyltf.netdna-cdn.com says:
>
> > WARNING! Please Install Update To Continue.
>
> <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: Not enough info, where did you get this from?

Comment: According to [Norton](https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show_mobile?name=new1getallfilesnow.maynemyltf.netdna-cdn.com) that site may be spreading trojans/virus check your computer.

Comment: Users who post such low-quality questions are typically people who don't know where to start looking because they're not particularly computer literate. It's best that we try to guide the user towards a solution, not turn them away.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you're getting this on one particular site, then that site has been compromised

- These messages are typically generated by malware on the site as a result of an attacker compromising the site. You should disconnect from the Internet, then hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to close the dialog and close the browser immediately. If your browser is set to retain your session, you may want to close the tab in question before closing the browser so that it isn't reopened when you restart it. You may also want to clear your recent browsing history.
- Once you close the browser, you should perform a full system scan on your computer using your antivirus software to determine if you computer has been infected. These sites will often try to exploit security holes in browsers to install malware without your consent or knowledge, so it's important to make sure the system isn't compromised by some hidden virus.

#### If this pop-up isn't specific to one site, your computer is probably infected

- If you're seeing this pop-up on several sites, your computer is probably infected with malware. This is often the result of adware or a malicious browser plugin, but can result from more complex types of malware. Once again, you'll need to run a full system scan using an antivirus program.

Let us know what the results of the scan are, so we can better help you. See also: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)